# How to identify if file is a named pipe in java

Tags: java, named-pipes

How can we identify whether given File is a **named pipe**? Any way to use same code for both Linux and Windows.

Comment: on unix-type systems, you'd use `stat()` to get details about a file, which would include its internal filesystem-type.

Comment: @Cruncher The question is about named pipes, not shell redirection. Entirely different subjects.

Answer (score 4):

You may have some success with [isOther()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/attribute/BasicFileAttributes.html#isOther%28%29) in the NIO2 Files API. This tells you that it is not a file, not a directory, and not a link. That leaves a named pipe, a unix socket, or a device..... perhaps that's enough for you?